# User Input Perl Programs with Sublime Text 2

Tags: perl, sublimetext2, read-eval-print-loop, sublimerepl

I have been writing scripts and building them no problem. But what about when I want to accept user input?

I installed SublimeREPL and selected the perl package but I am not sure how to run my program using this console.

I haven't seen any documentation, I saw a video of someone running a python script and typing 'run' but that didn't seem to work for perl.

Answer (score 0):

Is SublimeREPL supposed to be Perl-able? I don't think so. Maybe you should try to run tour script directly from your favorite terminal emulator using `perl myscript.pl`.

Comment: SublimeREPL has a built in PERL setting/emulator but I don't see any documentation on the syntax or commands to run my scripts

Comment: Does a software with a feature is supposed to be missing the documentation about it ? You can't use it. If it's not documented, the feature don't exists.

Answer (score 0):

The included Perl REPL (`Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Perl/re.pl`) is basically a very short perl program to `eval()` input one line at a time:

```
$| = 1;

    while(true) {
        print "perl>  ";
        $line=<>;
        $value=eval($line);
        $error=$@;
        if( $error ne "" ) { 
                print $error; 
            } else { 
                print "$value\n"; 
        }
    }
```

and, honestly, leaves a lot to be desired.

However, a quick search of CPAN revealed [Devel::REPL](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Devel-REPL-1.003015/lib/Devel/REPL.pm), which you could try running in SublimeREPL. Create the following as `Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Perl/Main.sublime-menu`:

```
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"caption": "Perl",
                "id": "Perl",

                 "children":[
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Devel::REPL",
                     "id": "repl_perl",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["/path/to/perl", "/path/to/Devel/REPL/re.pl"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Perl/Perl.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "devel_repl"
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            }]
        }
]
```

This will add a new `Perl` submenu to your `Tools` menu with a single `Devel::REPL` option. I don't have a chance to test it now, so good luck!